# Svg grayscale filter in firefox error

Tags: firefox, svg, filter, svg-filters

I'm using a svg filter on the website I'm currently working on. It's supposed to desaturate the images and when I hover they should return to their normal coloured state. I used an online tutorial and it works great in Chrome, IE, safari, .. But in firefox the images don't show, it's just blanc, and when you hover above them they suddenly show in their coloured state. I have tried searching for a solution but the only similar case I found was because of a wrong ID.

My svg code:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <filter id="grayscale">
  <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"/>
 </filter>
</svg>
```

My css code:

```
#thumbnails li img
{
    width: 31%;
    filter: url(filters.svg#grayscale); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
    filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Google Chrome & Safari 6+ */
    margin-bottom: 1.3%;
    margin-top: 1.3%;
}

#thumbnails img:hover 
{
    filter: none;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
}
```

The console error I get in firefox is:

> Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped

If you need extra information I'd be happy to provide it.
Thanks a lot in advance.
Timothy

Answer (score 0):

For future references (as this is quite an old question and I'm not sure if OP even needs this anymore...)

.SVG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg version="1.1"
     baseProfile="full"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <filter id="grayscale">
        <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0
                                             0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0
                                             0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0
                                             0      0      0      1 0"/>
    </filter>
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
.YOUR_DIV img {
    width: 260px;
    height: 190px;
     filter: grayscale(100%); /* Current draft standard */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* New WebKit */
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(100%); 
    -o-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Not yet supported in Gecko, Opera or IE */ 
    filter: url(PATH/TO/SVG/**filter**.svg#grayscale); /* Gecko */
    filter: gray; /* IE */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Old WebKit */
}

.YOUR_DIV img:hover {
    filter: none;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
}
```

*Be sure to change the path and name of your filter in the CSS to match your file.svg and ID.